# JAWS not able to read values from select drop down when expanded

Tags: angular, select, jaws-screen-reader

In my angular 4 app, I have 2 select drop down with some values. The requirement is JAWS should be able to read the drop down values when it is expanded and value is selected. I user SPACEBAR to open the drop down and use ARROWKEYS to traverse through the values.
In the below example, JAWS is able to read the values from first drop down , but not the second drop down.
I am not able to find what exactly is the issue in second drop down.
Is the change method in second drop down causing JAWS not able to read the value or am I missing anything?
I tried to add 'aria-label' to the options, still not working.

```
**Dropdown1**   
   <select class="dropdownclass" tabindex="1"
                  aria-label="Select drop down 1" formControlName="dropdown1" >
                  <option value="" aria-label="Select drop down1"></option>
                  <option value="greater">></option>
                  <option value="less"><</option> 
                </select> 

**Dropdown2**  
  <select class="dropdownclass" tabindex="2"
                        aria-label="Select Confidentiality" formControlName="dropdown2" 
                        (change)="doSomething(form.controls['dropdown2'])">
                        <option value="" aria-label="Select drop down2"></option>
                        <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                        <option value="0" >No</option>
                      </select>
```

Comment: you need aria-labelledby.

Comment: check this https://dev.to/emmabostian/creating-a-custom-accessible-drop-down-3gmo

Comment: https://dev.to/emmabostian/creating-a-custom-accessible-drop-down-3gmo

Comment: @Sean, I took a glance the link, should we use only <ul> and <li> and use aria-labelledby. If that is the case, how is the first down working?